# How do I find and look at a specific pixel in a tiff file?

Tags: python, colors, tiff

I have a tiff file and was wondering how to find the specific pixel value and read the color of it on python 3. It is a grayscale photo though, but RGB format would be very helpful (R,B,G). It could be another format if it would become very complicated. There are multiple pixels I want to read on this tiff file. I know the exact location of the pixel I want, but don't know how to get the pixel value for it so I can find the color.

The overall goal of this is to find the color of the certain pixel, not find the pixel value.